# Unknown error playing a video with EasyVideoPlayer

Tags: java, android, video

I'm trying to play a video from a given URL in Android Studio. Video's format is MP4. Sometimes it gets played. But sometimes it gives me this error:

```
D/EasyVideoPlayer: Loading web URI: http://example.com/video.mp4
V/MediaHTTPService: MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@5f993a4): Cookies: null
V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection: CookieHandler (java.net.CookieManager@dcee5c2) exists.
V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@5f993a4): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@dcee5c2 Cookies: null
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x993d8be0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb0fcce50)
W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 5772076 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
W/System.err: java.lang.Exception: Preparation/playback error (1): Unknown error
W/System.err:     at com.afollestad.easyvideoplayer.EasyVideoPlayer.onError(EasyVideoPlayer.java:698)
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3299)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
D/EasyVideoPlayer: onCompletion()
```

I'm stuck at this point on what's wrong and how to manage this. I've tried to put a retry logic on `onError` override of the `EasyVideoCallback`, but I don't know what to do. Can you help?

Update: [EasyVideoPlayer is an android library that facilitates playing video](https://github.com/afollestad/easy-video-player)

Comment: What is easy video player ?? Is it a library ? There is VideoView in Android not EasyVideoPlayer .

Comment: can you share lib link

Comment: Are you sure the url you are using is correct or contains data?  I can’t reach the url showing in your logs (http://example.com/video.mp4)

Comment: @fatemehfallahiarezoudar, that's a fake URL just as a sample.

Comment: Use this url as your sample please (http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) .   Your fake url can’t be played by the player.

Comment: I'm using a real URL of course. I used that fake URL because of privacy. Otherwise I'm using a real MP4 URL that is played sometimes.